# In API call get data How to restrict some attributes to be fetched?

Tags: magento2, certification

By default, all attribute is got by using the API calls so just want to restrict some attribute is not able to fetch via API call how can we achieve same? how to send only select attribute in API call?

E.g http://localhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/products/:sku

above API call give all details about the product so I want to restrict some attribute and those attributes are not included in result

How it's possible any idea?